# Should I be worried about the user's possibilities to tamper code while inspecting the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a self-taught web developer and I've learned a lot throughout the years from more experienced developers, but there is one thing that is always bugging me...

The idea that any user can see and edit anything created using "front-end technologies", i.e. HTML, CSS, JavaScript.
I feel I am too paranoid about this, but wanted to hear from people that are more experienced and skilled than I am.

Obviously, I know I should secure the website so that all the imaginable actions from the user can be proofed, but I still can't help but wonder, is it enough?
I understand this is a general question and it's hard to answer, but consider the next situation.

I am building a website with substantial number of modals, or pop-ups.
An example would be a log in modal. 
When a user clicks on the "log in" button, I display the log in modal and hide it once it is closed.

Now consider multiple of these modals being hidden from the user, but they still appear as hidden elements when the website is inspected.
A user could then display the modals while editing CSS which would cause issues if these modals are displayed where they shouldn't be displayed.

This is a crude example, but is this considered "bad practice/code structure"?
I am just very confused if this is completely insignificant since it isn't the "normal" functionality of the website, or if this is important and I should carefully structure what is shown in the inspection window of the browser.

Hopefully someone will shed some light on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: It's considered back practice but not for "security" reasons, but performance ones. Sure you'll take the hit for constructing the popup only once, but you'll take an extended hit throughout the lifetime of the user's session as you hold all this junk in memory. You'll only need that login modal once on average.

Comment: Code your server so it complies with the adage *"Never trust the client"* and you're all set. Your paranoia will go away.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas So what do you suggest then?
Should I remove modals from the DOM or you had something else in mind?

Comment: @MSiric - Create the modal if and when you need it. Destroy it afterwards. I inherited a huge, sluggish legacy webapp that created all of its views, modals, etc. and held them in memory (just hidden) until needed. It had the habit of occasionally crashing the user's browser. You need to evaluate your own use cases though. And for "security" concerns, follow Nik's advice and never trust the user -- redo any validation on the server side, double check all data that you receive, and don't leave any goodies hidden in the dom for them to find.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks for the advice, my mind is finally settled now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the code visible to the user doesn't contain anything that should be *secret* and known only to the server, it's definitely not something to bother with. There are an uncountable number of ways for anyone to break a website by opening the console or developer tools and by deleting/moving elements or typing in Javascript of their own. Making a website impenetrable to this sort of tweaking would be impossible.

If the website breaks as a result of a user's own tampering, that's on them, not the site designer (and, worst case, they can just refresh the page to get back to the working-as-designed page). As long as nothing meant to be secret is sent to the client, feel free to build pages with the assumption that the end user will not run any custom Javascript or make any changes on their own. They *may* do so, of course, but as long as it doesn't allow them to do things that cause problems for other users or the server (like accepting unverified input on the backend, or sending something that should be secret to the client), it shouldn't be something to worry about.

Comment: Build pages with the assumption that the end user will not run any custom JavaScript? I’m not so sure that is a safe assumption. If you build a website and the server sends data for all the users, and the client only shows the information relevant to that user. That is bad. You still have to think about security. If an attacker can run custom JavaScript and cause a bad result or a security problem, that is bad.

Comment: That's what the first sentence of the answer was meant to address, should have been more clear. Don't trust the client, of course, but as long as everything that should be secret stays with the server, further possible tweaks made by the client shouldn't be something to bother with guarding against (because it's unnecessary and impossible)